# List of objects. Unable to add object to list<object>

Tags: c#, list, object

I am trying to make list of object as

```
 List<FeedItem> List_feeds = new List<FeedItem>();
 FeedItem objFeedItem = new FeedItem();

objFeedItem.feedId = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
.
.
.
.
objFeedItem.text  = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerXml;
objFeedItem.imgthumb = thumbImage;
objFeedItem.imglarge = largeImage;

 List_feeds.Add(objFeedItem);
```

**Error**: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Some One asked for the compleate Code hear it is..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;

namespace FSB.Classes
{
    public class FeedItem
    {
        public string feedId{ get; set; }
        public string feed_publishDate{ get; set; }
        public string feed_createDate{ get; set; }
        public string feed_modifieddate{ get; set; }
        public string title{ get; set; }
        public string description{ get; set; }
        public string text{ get; set; }
        public string imgthumb{ get; set; }
        public string imglarge{ get; set; }
        public string addedBy{ get; set; }
        public string edited{ get; set; }
        public string createDate{ get; set; }
        public string updateDat { get; set; }
    }


    public class Feeds
    {

        protected string newsURL;
        protected List<FeedItem> List_feeds;

        public Feeds()
        {
            newsURL = @"http://api.brafton.com/55f3e621-2223-48de-bafc-4f3774e72533/news/";
             List<FeedItem> List_feeds = new List<FeedItem>();
        }


        public void updateAllFeeds()
        {
            getFeedList();


        }

        private void getFeedList()
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument objFeedDoc = new XmlDocument();
                var nodeFeedList = getFeedNodes();

                foreach (XmlNode objFeedNode in nodeFeedList)
                {
                    string feedDetailhref = objFeedNode.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    string strFeedDetail = getFeedDetailXml(feedDetailhref);

                    objFeedDoc.LoadXml(strFeedDetail);
                    XmlNode feedNode = objFeedDoc.SelectSingleNode("newsItem");

                    FeedItem objFeedItem = new FeedItem();


                    objFeedItem.feedId =feedNode.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;


                    objFeedItem.feedId              = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
                    objFeedItem.feed_publishDate    = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("publishDate").InnerText;
                    objFeedItem.feed_createDate     = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("createdDate").InnerText;
                    objFeedItem.feed_modifieddate   = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("lastModifiedDate").InnerText;
                    objFeedItem.title               = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("headline").InnerText;
                    objFeedItem.description         = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("htmlMetaDescription").InnerText;
                    objFeedItem.text                = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerXml;


                    string thumbImage = "";
                    string largeImage = "";
                   /*
                    try
                    {

                        string pictureURL = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("photos").Attributes["href"].Value;
                        XmlNode imageNode = getFeedImage(pictureURL);
                        foreach (XmlNode pic in imageNode)
                        {
                            if (pic.SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText.ToLower() == "large")
                            {
                               largeImage = pic.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText;

                            }
                            if (pic.SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText.ToLower() == "thumb")
                            {
                               thumbImage = pic.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText;

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Write(ex.Message);
                    }
                    */
                    objFeedItem.imgthumb = thumbImage;
                    objFeedItem.imglarge = largeImage;




                    List_feeds.Add(objFeedItem);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        private XmlNode getFeedImage(string pictureURL)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument picDoc = new XmlDocument();
                var client = new WebClient();
                var content = client.DownloadString(newsURL);

                picDoc.LoadXml(content);
               return picDoc.SelectSingleNode("photos/photo/instances");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;

        }

        /*Extract the newsListItem from the xml Feeds */
         private XmlNodeList getFeedNodes()
         {
             try
             {
                 XmlDocument docFeed = new XmlDocument();
                 string strFeedXml = getFeedXml();
                 docFeed.LoadXml(strFeedXml);
                 return docFeed.SelectNodes("news/newsListItem");
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Console.Write(ex.Message);
             }
             return null;
         }

        /*Get the Xml Feeds From the Live Server*/
        private string getFeedXml()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new WebClient();
                var content = client.DownloadString(newsURL);
                return content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }

        /*Get the Xml Feeds Details From the Live Server*/
        private string getFeedDetailXml(string newsDetailURL)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new WebClient();
                var content = client.DownloadString(newsDetailURL);
                return content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: last line `List_feeds.Add(objFeedItem);`

Comment: Can you post a small runnable program which we can copy and run on our system.

Comment: probably the xml node that you are selecting is missing

Comment: no the node is not missing . i have checked. all the nodes and value

Comment: Down voters please comment why?

Comment: I have added the compleate code now pleas can you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of

```
protected List<FeedItem> List_feeds;
```

is never instantiated.

Change it to

```
protected List<FeedItem> List_feeds = new List<FeedItem>();
```

and remove this from the constructor:

```
List<FeedItem> List_feeds = new List<FeedItem>();
```

This is because the code in the constructor was simply creating a local variable of the same name as your class level variable, instead of actually instantiating a class level object (as I think you intended)

Comment: it worked... thanks...but i did the reverse i changed the line in cunstructor from  `List<FeedItem> List_feeds = new List<FeedItem>();` to  `List_feeds = new List<FeedItem>();`

Comment: can you tell me which one is better .... to instantiat when declared or in constructor ?

Comment: Instantiate when declared will instantiate it before any code in the constructor runs.  If you instantiate it in the constructor, you have to make sure it is created before any code that accesses it trys to use it.  On the other hand, you get control of when the memory allocation occurs.  In short, it depends on your situation :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var idNode = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("id");
if (idNode != null) {
    objFeedItem.feedId = idNode.InnerText;
    ...
}

var textNode = feedNode.SelectSingleNode("text");
if (textNode != null) {
    objFeedItem.text  = textNode.InnerXml;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<FeedItem> List_feeds = new List<FeedItem>();
```

in the constructor you are instantiating a local variable not the global one.