# C# a having a list inside a list of objects. Will not allow .add

Tags: c#, list, nullreferenceexception

I keep getting this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CustomerExcelreader.exe

Additional information:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which I don't know why, since I have a global object, and I know the object works, since when I use non-list values of the object, everything works just fine.

This is the actual object in question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomerExcelreader
{
public class customers
{
    public customers()
    {

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// These work just fine.
    /// </summary>
    public String Guest { get; set; }
    public String Contact { get; set; }
    public String ClubNumber { get; set; }//GuestNumber
    public String CasioNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lists of lists
    /// </summary>
    public List<String> Dates { get; set; }
    public List<String> Description { get; set; }
    public List<Double> moneyIN { get; set; }
    public List<Double> moneyOUT { get; set; }
    public List<Double> Balance { get; set; }
    public List<String> Remarks { get; set; }

}
}
```

and here is where it messes up with any of the List values, but normal variables are fine.

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //customers add_customerHistory;
    if (listNames.SelectedIndex >= 0)// && listNames.SelectedIndex <= Pathlist.Capacity)//somehow SelectedIndex could be less then 0 by not picking something.
    {
        //add_customerHistory = CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex];
        textBox1.Text = CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].ClubNumber;
        CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].Dates.Add(DateBox.Text);
        CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].Description.Add(DescriptionBox.Text);
        CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].moneyIN.Add(Convert.ToDouble(InBox.Text));
        CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].moneyOUT.Add(Convert.ToDouble(OutBox.Text));
        CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].Balance.Add(Convert.ToDouble(BalanceBox.Text));
        CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].Remarks.Add(RemarkBox.Text);
        //CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].CasioNumber = "Its been changed";
        richTextBox1.Text = CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].CasioNumber;

    }
    else
    {
        CustomerHistoryList[0].Dates.Add(DateBox.Text);
        CustomerHistoryList[0].Description.Add(DescriptionBox.Text);
        CustomerHistoryList[0].moneyIN.Add(Convert.ToDouble(InBox.Text));
        CustomerHistoryList[0].moneyOUT.Add(Convert.ToDouble(OutBox.Text));
        CustomerHistoryList[0].Balance.Add(Convert.ToDouble(BalanceBox.Text));
        CustomerHistoryList[0].Remarks.Add(RemarkBox.Text);
    }

}
```

It seems odd that it doesn't work here. I guess it has something to do with lists inside of objects? I heard those can act funky.

Comment: have you set the lists to an instance?

Comment: Slip my mind completely, thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of objects. Unable to add object to list<object>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156755/list-of-objects-unable-to-add-object-to-listobject)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialise your `list<String>` properties in your class constuctor.

```
public class customers
{
    public customers()
    {
       Dates = new List<String>();
       Description = new List<String>();
       moneyIN  = new List<Double>();
       moneyOUT = new List<Double>();       
       Balance =  new List<Double>();
       Remarks = new List<String>();
    }


    // Other bits (not copied)



}
```

Comment: Did not know you needed to do that.

Comment: `List<T>` is an object type and, by default, will initialise to NULL when you instantiate your class. Same with any object type

Comment: Did not know that ether.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new instance of a class (*List* in your case), before accesing its members (*Add* method in your case).

For example:

```
CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].Dates = new List<string>();
CustomerHistoryList[listNames.SelectedIndex].Dates.Add(DateBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Hammond pointed out, just because you use a property setter/getter does not mean that it will automatically create property values for you.  This only happens with non nullable value types.

Either put the logic in your constructor or change them to private fields.

```
public class customers
{
    public customers()
    {
        this.Dates = new List<String>();
        this.Description = new List<String>();
        ...
    }
```

This makes it tricky for inheritance, so you can utilize private fields

```
public class customers
{
    private List<String> _dates = new List<String>();
    private List<String> _description = new List<String>();

    public List<String> Dates
    { 
        { return _dates; }
        { _dates = value; }
    }

    public List<String> Description
    { 
        { return _description; }
        { _description = value; }
    }

    ....
```

See this other post about exposing Generic Lists as Properties

[Why is it considered bad to expose List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387937/why-is-it-considered-bad-to-expose-listt?rq=1)

Comment: Just curious... why does it _make it tricky for inheritance_?

Comment: I could never wrap my head around this.X or this.Y.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) then :)

Comment: The "tricky inheritance" suggestion was for Code Analysis rule CA2214 which pertains to overriding virtual properties
 
see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx [and]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963219/code-analysis-warning-2214-how-best-to-fix